# How do I set a JMS Publisher Provider URL to send Asynchronous messages in Jmeter GUI

Tags: asynchronous, jmeter, jms, jms-topic

A developer told me the string looked something like the below for the Provider URL field for a JMS Publisher

tcp://localhost:62616async=True, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it took such a long time to find this online for me. Below is the reference and answer.

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-asynchronous-sending.html

tcp://localhost:62616?**jms.useAsyncSend=true**